# Angular 2 + Angular Fire 2 login - not detecting change

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement what I think is a very simple and straight-forward behavior - routing to a different page once the login is done. However, some data is not updated in one of the components which makes me believe it has something to do with Angular 2's change detection.

This is my code:

Login component - part of the Pages module

```js
constructor(private _af: AngularFire,
            private _router: Router,
            private _zone: NgZone) {
}

onLoginSubmit() {
    this._af.auth.login({
        email: this.auth.email,
        password: this.auth.pass
    }).then( success => {
        this._zone.run(() => {
            this._router.navigate(['/']);
        });
    })
}
```

Dashboard component - part of the Pages module - route '/'

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this._stateService.currentPageName = 'Dashboard';
}
```

Topbar component - part of the UI module

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._router.events.subscribe(() => {
        this.pageName = this._stateService.currentPageName;
    });
}
```

Topbar template

```html
    <!--  This is not updated when I'm routing from the login page, 
          but it shows fine when I'm reloading the page or switching to any other routes -->
        <a class="navbar-brand">{{ pageName }}</a>
```

Comment: You could use Angular's ngOnChanges() life cycle hook to handle this kind of situation - because it will detect changes that happen later, not just those available on initialization.

Comment: I tried adding
`ngOnChanges() {
        this.pageName = this._stateService.currentPageName;
    }`
to the Topbar component, but still nothing happens. Is this the correct place to put it?

Comment: Also, the ngOnChanges lifecycle hook only reacts to changes of the Input values, not values throughout the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that your `router.events` are fired before you are setting the `currentPageName`.

Quick and easy solution: Using a `BehaviorSubject` inside of your `StateService` instead of a simple `string`.

```js
currentPageName = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
```

Setting a new value inside of your `Dashboard` component:

```js
ngOnInit() {
   this._stateService.currentPageName.next('Dashboard');
   // or create a function inside of your service
   // this._stateService.setCurrentPage('Dashboard');
}
```

Using this `BehaviorSubject` directly inside of your `Topbar` template:

```html
<a class="navbar-brand">{{ _stateService.currentPageName | async }}</a>
```

Comment: That was indeed the issue, the events were triggered too late rather than too early. However, I decided to just create a new component for the route name and just hook into ngOnChanges to display the value. That did the trick.

Your solution does sound like it would work, but can you explain what the BehaviorSubject does compared to a normal Subject?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The trick with `BehaviorSubject` is, that it holds the last value. You can access it via `.value`. With a "normal" `Subject` you will only be triggered if there was a value-change. And your templates could only show a value if it was changed during its subscription. Pro for that `BehaviorSubject`, your template will always show a value! :)